# Unable to link CSS to the template url react content query web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, css, content-query-web-part, template

I have just installed the react Content query web part and I am linking the template url to html files in my site assets, I have a common css which has some elements common across different templates but though there is proper reference it is unable to render the stylesheet has anyone come across this issue

Answer (score 0):

Per my test it works well, I copy the existing tempalte then create a new html file which change the font to 100, upload it to site assests library, fill in the template URL, it will show the changed font.

[image]

[image]

Please make sure the template is correct, also try to edit the template content directly to compare the result.

Comment: Thanks for responding to the query Julie , the only issue is that is that it doesn't take the color property in the external stylesheet, but if I put the color property to pick up site theme color in the internal stylesheet it works

Comment: what did you mean external and internal stylesheet?